# How do I correctly bump the version number when building a kernel package from git?

Tags: kernel, packaging

When building a patched kernel from [Ubuntu kernel git repositories](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide) how do I change the version numbers so that the resulting kernel package has the following properties:

1. Installs files in /boot/ which are named differently than the current official kernel on which it is based, and thus do not conflict.
2. Appears "newer" than the current official kernel on which it is based, so it is automatically selected at boot time.
3. Appears older than the next official kernel release, so that it will be replaced when there is a kernel update.

Answer (score 1):

Package versions come from the most recent changelog entry. So add a changelog entry, with `dch -i`. The best way to ensure the version will be lower than the next official upload, is to just append something to the end of the previous version, like `+local1`.

Comment: Does not work. The kernel.git does not include a debian/changelog so "dch -i" fails.